# how to retrieve inbox messages of last 5 days?

Tags: java, android

Hi I am able to retrieve all inbox message, but i want to retrieve message of only last 5 days how to achieve this.

```
        private void readMessage(){
            Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body", "date" };
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

        }

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have where clause on date column to retrieve all data have date greater than 5 days ago. Please check below sample code.

```
private static final long FIVE_DAYS_MILIS = 24 * 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    private void readMessage() {
        Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        long currentTimeMilis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Time milis before 5 days
        long milisBefore5Days = currentTimeMilis - FIVE_DAYS_MILIS;
        // Where clause saying that date should be greater that milis before 5
        // days.
        String selection = "date > ?";
        String selectionArgs[] = { Long.toString(milisBefore5Days) };
        String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body", "date" };
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    }
```

Hope This Helps!